# Netsuite : Advanced PDF / HTML Template - Declaring Variables

Tags: netsuite

Can anyone guide me on how to declare variables?
I want to store the field values(not empty) in 1 variable then displays it.

${record.createdfrom.entity.shipaddressee} ${record.createdfrom.entity.shipcountry} ${record.shipcity}

Above is the fields that I've been using.
I really have no Idea on how to do this.

Comment: Did either of the answers help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/index.html

You have to keep in mind that NetSuite is currently only using FreeMarker Version 2.3.26-incubating. Some of the options may not be available that are found in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of examples from one of my PDFs.

```
<#assign showPrices=record.custbody_hs_show_line_item_prices>
<#assign discounts=[]>
<#assign discountsCount=0>
<#assign discountStr="">
<#assign lineValues={}>
<#assign discounts=discounts+[{"item":item.item,"amount":item.amount}]>
<#assign lineValues=lineValues+{"item":item.item,"description":item.description,"quantity":0,"rate":0,"amount":0,"taxrate":item.taxrate1,"billCycle":item.billingcycle}>
```

That should give you an idea of the different types of assignment statements.

Answer (score 0):

you can use <#assign>
for example 
<#assign count = 0>
this will assign '0' to the variable count